# Memory Leak in DNN 9 MVC modules

Tags: asp.net-mvc, memory-leaks, dotnetnuke

We are getting a memory leak on an azure app service running a DNN front end website containing predominantly WebForm but also some MVC modules.

I ran a memory dump through dotMemory and found that by far the largest retained size was taken up by the ViewEngineCollection object type.

As far as my understanding goes this should contain the Razor view engine as well as any others used in the web app.

What I am finding is instead each instance of each MVC object is being added as view engines to the collection and are never being garbage collected - taking gigabytes worth of memory. At time of memory dump >90% were in gen2 memory so they are long-lived.

Consider an MVC module, MyMVCModule. Let's say there is an action tag in the .cshtml which contains a dynamically generated url - it seems that when the MVC object is instantiated an object comparer determines equivalency with other objects already in the collection. Any small difference in versions of the same module will cause it to be added as a "new" engine to memory. I believe this is a caching function but there are so many permutations that by orders of magnitude the costs of storage outweigh the costs of reinstantiating our MVC objects.There are thousands of copies of the module in memory.

The dictionary is a child of ModuleDelegatingViewEngine which is a dnn specific component, so I don't believe this issue is to do with the MVC framework in general.

[image: partial screenshot of dotMemory output]

Is this usual behaviour? If so, is there a way I can get the garbage collector to clear these pages earlier? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A few answers/notes for you.  Not a 100% answer, but more than a comment.

1. This is NOT normal and shouldn't be the situation
2. Items like this should be logged to the project itself https://www.github.com/dnnsoftware/dnn.platform where they can be tracked/managed.
3. We are working an issue, specifically with WebAPI modules that might be related: https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/issues/3186

Could you confirm which specific version of 9.x you are using?  ANy chance of submitting a sample module as well?

Comment: We are on DNN v. 09.00.01

Comment: Issues on the dnn github page are accepted only for more current versions of dnn - let me know if you would like me to raise the issue anyway and I will.

Comment: @S4vrs3nC0de given that you are not on 9.4.1, I would be curious to know what extensions are you using on the site.  Do you have a lot of custom stuf?

Comment: We essentially use zero extensions from store/forge - all of our modules, save a couple of html modules, are either custom webforms or custom mvcs. We basically use DNN as a thin wrapper over dotnet.